# Локализация массива строковых значений в Info.plist через InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, локализация

В Info.Plist есть массив строковых данных. Его нужно локализовать. Как этот массив описать в InfoPlist.strings? основной затык в том, что формат .strings предполагает:

**"key" = "value"**

а про массивы никто и ничего не написал. Возможно ли и если да, то как?

Comment: Опиши более детально вопрос и лучше всего привести наглядный пример того как есть и что должно произойти или получиться

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, зачем локализовывать массив.
Если нужно локализовать каждый элемент массива, то создавайте на каждый элемент по строке и локализуйте их по одной.

Если нужно локализовать перечисление (чтобы в соответствии с правилами языка расставлялись запятые и союзы "и"), то пользуйтесь ListFormatter (iOS 13+).

Ресурса "массив строк" для локализации, как в Android (наверное, вы поэтому спрашиваете) в iOS нет.